# Storing and Displaying Articles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What is the best way to store long text in a database that will be displayed as articles on a webpage? As a long string?

And another quick question, is there a way to limit the amount objects on one side of a many to many relationship: for example I have a fight and a fighter entities which have a many to many relationship but I want to only allow there to be two fighters in a fight. What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: If you have two questions, please put them in two separate questions.  These two appear to be completely unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think that the restriction of 2 fighters in a fight will be set in stone, you may be better off having 2 columns to store the fighter id; for example: `fighter1_id` and `fighter2_id`.

As far as long text in the table, usually `nvarchar(max)` is recommended.